# Trouble loading a custom ViT model with from_pretrained() method in Hugging Face Transformers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I want to fine-tune a ViT model to be able to predict nine continuous values per sample that represent size proportion. The sum of these nine values is therefore equal to one.
I have defined the following model class, that inherits from the parent class "ViTPretrainedModel" in order to be able to call `from_pretrained()` method afterwards :

```
class ViTForRegression(ViTPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, model_name_or_path, num_labels=NB_SIEVING_SIZE):
        config = ViTConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
        super().__init__(config)
        self.model = ViTModel.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
        self.regressor = torch.nn.Linear(self.model.config.hidden_size, num_labels)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.KLDivLoss(reduction='batchmean')

    def forward(self, pixel_values, labels=None):
        outputs = self.model(pixel_values=pixel_values)
        logits = self.regressor(outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0])
        logits = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
        log_probs = torch.log(logits) # we log the softmax (probabilities) for the KLDivLoss
        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.loss_fn(log_probs, labels)
        return { 'logits': logits, 'loss': loss }
```

I then create the model using a pretrained ViT model and its weights and train it using the Trainer class from transformers library.

```
model = ViTForRegression.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=10)],
)

train_results = trainer.train()
```

The performances on my validation set are very good and encouraging, so I save my model using the `save_pretrained()` method

```
model.save_pretrained(os.path.join(SAVED_MODELS_PATH, 'regression_vit')
```

But now I don't know how to load my model from another script. What I tried is to defined the same class as I did here and then to load the model with :

```
model = model = ViTForRegression.from_pretrained(os.path.join(SAVED_MODELS_PATH, 'regression_vit'))
```

But I can't load it and I get the following error :

```
HFValidationError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/pa_orcademo_torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py:629, in PretrainedConfig._get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    627 try:
    628     # Load from local folder or from cache or download from model Hub and cache
--> 629     resolved_config_file = cached_file(
    630         pretrained_model_name_or_path,
    631         configuration_file,
    632         cache_dir=cache_dir,
    633         force_download=force_download,
    634         proxies=proxies,
    635         resume_download=resume_download,
    636         local_files_only=local_files_only,
    637         use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
    638         user_agent=user_agent,
    639         revision=revision,
    640         subfolder=subfolder,
    641         _commit_hash=commit_hash,
    642     )
    643     commit_hash = extract_commit_hash(resolved_config_file, commit_hash)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pa_orcademo_torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:417, in cached_file(path_or_repo_id, filename, cache_dir, force_download, resume_download, proxies, use_auth_token, revision, local_files_only, subfolder, repo_type, user_agent, _raise_exceptions_for_missing_entries, _raise_exceptions_for_connection_errors, _commit_hash)
    415 try:
    416     # Load from URL or cache if already cached
--> 417     resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
...
  "qkv_bias": true,
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.29.2"
}
' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

I don't if I save my model the wrong way, or if it is the loading that causes the issue.
I would really appreciate your help.

I've tried to :

- Load a pretrained custom ViT model after having trained and saved it using `model.save_pretrained()` method.

I expected that :

- the model is load and I can do prediction with it

What resulted :

- model loading failed

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to execute your code sample because `from_pretrained` already raised an error.

The `from_pretrained` method you inherit from ViTPreTrainedModel passes a ViTConfig object to the `__init__` of your ViTForRegression class ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/118e9810687dd713b6be07af79e80eeb1d916908/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L2610)) and not a string as shown in your example. You can pass this config object directly to ViTModel instead of calling from_pretrained again.

I would also include your additional parameter `num_labels` with a custom prefix (to avoid interfering with hf code) in the config.

```py
import torch
from transformers import ViTPreTrainedModel, ViTConfig, ViTModel

class ViTForRegression(ViTPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config: ViTConfig):
        #not needed because config is already passed
        #config = ViTConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
        super().__init__(config)
        self.vit = ViTModel(config)
        self.regressor = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.my_num_labels)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.KLDivLoss(reduction='batchmean')

        self.post_init()

    def forward(self, pixel_values, labels=None):
        outputs = self.vit(pixel_values=pixel_values)
        logits = self.regressor(outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0])
        logits = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
        log_probs = torch.log(logits) # we log the softmax (probabilities) for the KLDivLoss
        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.loss_fn(log_probs, labels)
        return { 'logits': logits, 'loss': loss }

model_id = 'google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k'
custom_config = ViTConfig.from_pretrained(model_id)
# adding custom parameter
custom_config.my_num_labels = 5 

model = ViTForRegression.from_pretrained(model_id, config=custom_config)
# Testing it
model.save_pretrained("blabla")
model_saved = ViTForRegression.from_pretrained('blabla')
all([torch.allclose(w1,w1) for w1,w2 in zip(model.parameters(), model_saved.parameters()) ])
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I tried things like that but the problem is that weights of the pretrained ViT model doesn't seem to be initialized... However, I want them to be initialized, as I want to finetune the pretrained model.
Is it supposed to be the self.post_init() effect ?

Comment: No, the weights are initialized by from_pretrained. It just performs some conversion ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/118e9810687dd713b6be07af79e80eeb1d916908/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L444)). The `model.vit` in my answer is initialized with the pre-trained weights.  @Ben-Jy